# MySQL variable is NULL after it was set

Tags: mysql, variables

I set a variable in MySQL and in the next `SELECT` query it is `NULL`.

```
SET @test = 123;
SELECT @test;
```

When executing the `SET` statement, there is no error.

Do I have to enable/activate the usage of variables?

I run MySQL Server 4.1.

Comment: 4.1 !! That is beyond ancient :O

Comment: Do you execute the statements from MySQL command line?.

Comment: Are you selecting in the same session as setting the variable?

Comment: Does `SELECT @test:=123` work?

Comment: Does setting a global variable work? `SELECT @@test=123`

Comment: I've got the same issue